# What does #var do?

Tags: bash, echo

By chance I produced the command `echo #a`, where `a=house`. The result of this command is blank, so I was intrigued started searching, but found nothing. So, why does `#a` evaluate to an empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the hash sign (`#`) is regarded as a comment in bash, so everything following `#` becomes a comment. In essence, if you have a line `echo #$a` or `echo #a` it will just print a blank line, which is the same as just typing `echo`.

If `a` is correctly assigned a value and you want to echo that value, you would do `echo $a`.